# How can i get the list of all opened apps on my desktop using electron.js not the list of processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, desktop-application

i have fetch all the procecsses using different npm packages like

- tasklist
- ps-list
- ps-node

in electron but still did not get the list of apps running on my desktop. i am using windows 10 and version of electron